# What's a good generative model for creating valid formats of a person's name?

Tags: generative-model

I'm trying to come up with a generative model that can input a name and output all valid formats of it.

For example, "Bob Dylan" could be an input and the gen model will output "Dylan, Bob", "B Dylan", "Bob D" and any other type of valid formatting of a person's name.  So given my example the gen model doesn't seem that complicated to build, but it also has to handle stuff like "Dylan, Bob" and "B Dylan", but obviously the 2nd one it shouldn't output "Bob Dylan" as a potential output cause inferring that requires more than just "B Dylan". Any ideas for a good Generative Model for this?

Comment: Do you really need a generative model to do this?

Comment: mmm well not if you can think of a better way?

Comment: @nbro if your looking some fun why not

Comment: @DylanY I would use an encoder decoder network like in translation systems and I’d induce a prior based on inputs (maybe a secondary step). Seems like a fun problem

Comment: like a VAE? What did you have in mind for doing it?

Comment: Why some rules should not work?

Comment: @OmG sorry what rules are you referring to?

Comment: @DylanY I mean grammatical rules.

Comment: well I'm more interested in how people would actually format names when writing them. I guess that is partially grammatical rules, but I think it's more useful for a gen model that can find the latent variables first name, middle name and last name.